# Can't locate storyboard constraints warnings in Xcode

Tags: xcode, autolayout, storyboard, constraints

Xcode is flagging constraint warnings up in the Issues Navigator pane, but when I select any of them, it doesn't take me to where the error should be in the storyboard / doesn't highlight any of the view controllers in the project overview pane as having issues.

None of my view controllers have the warning symbol next to them in the Document Outline either.

It's quite a big storyboard project. Is there a way to track the constraints causing these warnings down?

Comment: *"None of my view controllers have the warning symbol next to them in the Document Outline"* ... where are you seeing the constraint warnings then? Show a screen-cap of an example?